# Visiting Aruba for 10 days between two stays in the US

Tags: us-visa-waiver-program, australian-citizens, aruba

My Friends are Australian citizens and will be coming for a visit. They want to visit Aruba for approximately 2 weeks, after being in the US one month.

When they return from Aruba will they have 90 days again on their stay ?

Comment: They will most likely have to leave the US by the 90th day after their first arrival. In other words, their second stay will most likely be limited to a month and a half.

Comment: Aruba is not part of the USA in any way, they might reset their 90 days but it is up to the immigration officer on their return into the USA.

Comment: @Willeke the fact that Aruba isn't part of the US doesn't change the answer, however: the outlined itinerary will probably require the travelers to leave the US within 90 days of their first entry. The rule in question explicitly concerns trips outside the US, so I don't understand your point in asserting that Aruba isn't part of the US.

Comment: Aruba is also almost on the South American coast, not 'near the USA' in my view.

Comment: @Willeke my understanding of "nearby island" is that it denotes all of the Caribbean islands except Cuba.

Comment: Or rather *includes* those islands. I haven't been able to find an explicit list or a discussion of the definition of "adjacent."

Comment: @phoog The definition of adjacent islands is codified in US law, (INA 101(b)(5)) as "(5) The term “adjacent islands” includes Saint Pierre, Miquelon, Cuba, the Dominican Republic, Haiti, Bermuda, the Bahamas, Barbados, Jamaica, the Windward and Leeward Islands, Trinidad, Martinique, and other British, French, and Netherlands territory or possessions in or bordering on the Caribbean Sea." This definition appears to include Aruba, which is a Netherlands territory in the Caribbean Sea.

Comment: @MichaelHampton thanks.  I was looking for it in the CFR but apparently should have been looking in the US code.  The Cuba exclusion appears to apply to automatic revalidation, so I suppose it doesn't apply to the VWP rule.

Answer (score 2):

They will most likely have to leave the US by the 90th day after their first arrival. In other words, their second stay will most likely be limited to a month and a half.

See the State Department's web site (https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/visit/visa-waiver-program.html):

> Trips to Canada, Mexico, or nearby Islands
>
> If you are admitted to the United States under the VWP, you may take a short trip to Canada, Mexico, or a nearby island and generally be readmitted to the United States under the VWP for the remainder of the original 90 days granted upon your initial arrival in the United States. Therefore, the length of time of your total stay, including the short trip, must be 90 days or less. See the CBP website. Citizens of VWP countries* who reside in Mexico, Canada, or a nearby island are generally exempted from the requirement to show onward travel to another country* when entering the United States.

Comment: Hmm, there were recent reports that all references to the "nearby islands" rule seem to have disappeared from websites run by the Department of Homeland Security (under which the actual border guards belong) -- as if they've silently switched to a less rigid way of determining what to treat at an attempt at a VWP visa run. It seems only to have been an administrative practice anyway. On the other hand there also seems to be no explicit announcement that the "nearby islands" rule has been _abandoned_. It is _possible_ that changes just have not been reflected on Stated Department websites.

Comment: The "contiguous territory or adjacent islands" rule is in the code of federal regulations, so it can't be repealed without formal procedures, but the verb in that rule is "may," so I suppose the department could stop invoking it under its own discretion.

Comment: x @phoog: Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: @HenningMakholm see paragraph (b) at http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=a5aa1dbdf602028cca2db4feeae551e0&mc=true&node=se8.1.217_13&rgn=div8. (It's 8 CFR 1.217 in case the link breaks in the future.)

Comment: That looks to me more like it's about relaxing the requirement of arriving on a VWP-signatory carrier, than about constraining which length of stay the border guard can admit if you arrive from Canada/Mexico/Caribbean **with** a VWP-signatory carrier.

Comment: @HenningMakholm no, the "exception of arrival on a signatory carrier" is designed to enable people to fall under this provision even if they for example have crossed the land border to Canada or Mexico and are returning to the US other than by a signatory carrier.  That is, they must meet all conditions except that one to qualify.  (They may also qualify if they arrive on a signatory carrier, but it's not a requirement for qualification.)  Furthermore, it doesn't constrain the border guard.  It allows the border guard to constrain the traveller.